# Can a minimal model be infinite?

Tags: first-order-logic

Consider the follwoing first-order theory:

$$T=\{R(a,b); \forall x,y\,(R(x,y)\rightarrow \exists z\,R(y,z))\}$$

where $a,b$ are constants. Moreover, let us adopt the "standard name assumption", so that we can express every model for $T$ as a set of facts (i.e., ground atoms).

For what I know, $\mathcal{M}=\{R(a,b); R(b,c); R(c,a)\}$ is a minimal model for $T$.

Consider now a model $\mathcal{M}'$ for $T$ for which no such "cycle" on $R$ exists. Then $\mathcal{M}'$ must be infinite. Moreover, no model $\mathcal{M}''$ for $T$ can be such that $\mathcal{M}''\subset\mathcal{M}'$, unless we included "useless" facts in $\mathcal{M}'$ (suppose we didn't).

Then, does it make sense to say that $\mathcal{M}'$ is a *minimal* model for $T$, despite it is infinite?

Comment: Models are sets with interpretation of symbols from language, not a theory. What do you mean by  M={R(a,b),R(b,c), R(c,a)}?

Comment: @Antares That is just a shortcut notation, I thought its meaning was quite understandable. In description logics we often adopt the standard name assumtpion, where each constant symbol is interpreted as "itself" (see e.g. [this reference](https://www.dcs.bbk.ac.uk/~roman/papers/RW12014.pdf), at Definition 12). In this way, a model can be seen as a set of ground atoms. Anyway, feel free to skip that part, it was just an example.